# Automate switching between "complex" font styles in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, fonts

I'm writing learning journals for my school programming project, and I need to constantly switch between using Calibri, 12pt for my main text, and Courier, 11pt for the embedded code.

First I was manually switching the font and sizes, then I realized that that's ridiculous, so I looked up key-shortcuts, and ended up with the following set-up:

```
ctrl+!        -> Calibri
ctrl+@        -> Courier

ctrl+shift+p  -> Font size change dialog
```

This means any time I need to switch between the two, I need to enter two three-button combos, and navigate a list via the arrow keys. This is definitely better, but still a pain.

I could use an automation program to automatically enter the combos for me and traverse the size list, but ideally I'd like it all to happen via 1-key combo (changing both font and size), and have it happen all in the background.

Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to define separate styles for code and text, then record macros activate. Finally assign shortcuts to the macros.

Comment: `Selection.Font.Name = "Bell MT"`
`Selection.Font.Size = 12`

Answer (score 1):

Yes to separate styles, but you don't need macro.  You can assign a shortcut key to a style in the Modify Style dialog.